# Matrices in Python which follow a trend and have alterable dimension

Tags: python, arrays, loops, for-loop, matrix

Firstly, I want to be able to specify a value, n, which results in a particular nxn matrix being produced:
To do this I used the code:

```
n = __

np.eye (n)
```

Which will produce the identity matrix of the specified dimension, n.
However, I do not want to create the identity matrix precisely. Instead, I want to create the nxn matrix with entries that are equal to the column number of the particular entry.

Can I use np.eye(n) as a basis to solve my problem?

For example if I set n=3, I wish my code to form:

```
[1 , 2 , 3]
[1 , 2 , 3]
[1,  2 , 3]
```

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links on that page.

Comment: Maybe you could be more empathetic. My uni was on strike and I wasn't being taught the most content rich part of the course. Stress is very high right now and my work haven't let me know if I can get off for study leave.

Comment: @wwii please be nice. Consider that some people are not in the same position as you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use np.arange to generate the row, then repeat it using the following notation:

```
def matrix(n):
    row = np.arange(1,n+1)
    return np.array([row,]*n)
```

The [row,] notation adds our extra dimension, then we multiply it by n to get the size of our new dimension.

I think I can see what you're getting at with using np.eye(n), but I would use np.ones() instead:

```
def matrix(n):
    row = np.arange(1,n+1)
    return np.ones((3,3))*row
```

So we are just multiplying our sequence of natural numbers by a 3x3 array of ones to get our repeating rows.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to solve your problem. Since you want to use `np.eye`, maybe below solution could help.

```
import numpy as np

def matrix(n):
    x = np.eye(n)
    for i in range(n):
        x[i] = i + 1
    return x.T

def main():
    n=3
    print(matrix(n))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Output**

```
[[ 1.  2.  3.]
 [ 1.  2.  3.]
 [ 1.  2.  3.]]
```

Comment: Appreciate the response.

Comment: Would you be able to help me with a similar question over email? I'm not able to finish the remaining questions on my project without this one bit of code and it's driving me insane literally.